# Added simulated external display in Developer Settings and can't boot now

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, external-display

Got my S3 Mini with CM11 stuck at boot after adding external display simulation in Developer Settings. Just after that UI froze and I had to reboot. After that it freezes on "Android is upgrading" popup and the progress circle isn't even running.

I tried going to Safe Mode but the only difference is that the progress circle is running all the time but nothing happens for another hour.

Logcat says something like this:

```
I/DisplayManagerService( 2137): Display device added: DisplayDeviceInfo{"Nak┼éadka nr 1": 720 x 480, 60.000004 fps, density 160, 160.0 x 160.0 dpi, touch NONE, rotation 0, type OVERLAY, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_PRESENTATION}
E/gralloc ( 1671): gralloc_alloc: gralloc_alloc_framebuffer (google) failed, Out of memory
E/FramebufferNativeWindow( 1671): fb buffer 0 allocation failed w=480, h=800, err=Out of memory
```

Is there any way to remove the additional display without having to do data wipe? I have full access to ADB and recovery. Just this one thing stops Android to boot further.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wiping cache and dalvik before entering the safe mode. A similar problem is addressed on an XDA thread [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/help-messed-simulate-secondary-display-t2076180).

If the above doesn't work, you can restore the previous backup (hopefully a NAndroid one). If that doesn't work, you can try flashing CM again. Finally, if none of the above works, you can do a full data wipe and factory reset and flash + restore again.

Yet another approach is manually editing the developer options database via ADB as discussed [here](http://blog.jbit.net/2013/01/android-settings-reset-using-adb.html).

```
adb shell
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
delete from global where name="overlay_display_devices";
reboot
```

If the above doesn't work, then as said in above XDA thread, delete the developer settings manually as follows (all system specific settings will be reset), first mount /data in recovery:

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/
delete settings.db
reboot
```

If nothing works, the problem could be something different than the secondary display.

Comment: OMG this is great! Since noone answered I've done full wipe soon after the question. I was looking fo exactly such a solution (modyfying DB) which probably works. I'll reproduce the error and report later. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to disable the display overlay via ADB

```
adb shell settings put global overlay_display_devices null
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).